# For loop not returning all values

Tags: php, arrays

DB Values:

```
a_id  a_user_id  a_date     a_intime    a_outtime 
1       1       28/10/2014  12.30        1.30
2       1       29/10/2014  12.30        1.30
3       1       30/10/2014  12.30        1.30
```

The for loop returns only last  value. I want to return all `a_date` values.

```
   foreach ($query->result() as $row) {      
     $users= array( 
       'a_user_id' => $row->a_user_id,
       'a_date'=> $row->a_date,
       'a_intime'=>$row->a_intime,
       'a_outtime'=> $row->a_outtime   
     );
   }

   $b=date('g:i a',$bd);
   $ttime=($a-$b/3600);
   $total_time=date(' g:i ',$ttime);

   $user['total_hour']= $total_time; 
   return $user;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `$users` in the loop have to be an array

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $users[] = array( 
        'a_user_id' => $row->a_user_id,
        'a_date'=> $row->a_date,
        'a_intime'=>$row->a_intime,
        'a_outtime'=> $row->a_outtime
     );
}
```

Since it is `variable` it only hold the last occurrence of the loop.